# Center products on category if only 1 product exists?

Tags: magento2, category, products

I have some categories where the category only has 1 product that exists. Is there a way to center this product? Should really center up to 3 products since 4 completes the row.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to check the product count in your template and then add a class to the html container.

For example:

view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$count = $_productCollection->count();

<div class=" <?php echo ($count == 1)? 'product-center': '';?> products wrapper ......>

......

</div>
```

You need to write your custom css for this particular class.

Comment: I think it works.

Comment: Would that replace this code?         <div class="products wrapper <?php /* escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>"> Kind of confused